# php string synonym replace function

Tags: php, replace

I need to read from either an array or a file (preferably a file so it'd be easy to update) which contains acronyms and synonyms of common words and use that to find and replace in a string. For example, say CBN stands for "Cannot Be Negated". I need to replace "CBN king" with  "Cannot Be Negated king". How can i do this in PHP?

Comment: naive would be to load from a 2 column CSV

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use an INI file to store your translation table like so (translate.ini):

```
CBN     = "cannot be negated"
TTYL    = "talk to you later"
.
.
.
```

Read the file into an array like so:

```
$translate = parse_ini_file( '/path/translate.ini' );
```

Replace all acronyms with their full versions:

```
$toTranslate = "This CBN but it's too late so TTYL";
$translated  = str_ireplace( array_keys( $translate ), array_values( $translate ), $toTranslate );
```

(Please note the use if str_**i**replace() to avoid case issues).

Answer (score 1):

If it's not something you'd need to do very often (or in real time) a simple option would be compiling the "dictionary" file (let's say tab delimited, that contains acronyms and synonyms) first, then simply read all the content of it into a hashtable and then run str_replace(key, value) for each element in the hashtable against your source string.

Update: here what the code might look like:

```
$sourceString = 'My very long string full of acronyms like CBN';
$target = '';

//replace the following with file parsing routine
$myDict = array()
$myDict['CBN'] = 'Cannot Be Negated';
...
$myDict['PCBN'] = 'Probably Cannot Be Negated';
$myDict['MDCBN'] = 'Most Definitely Cannot Be Negated';

//replace acronyms with synonyms
foreach($myDict as $synonym=>$acronym)
    $target = str_replace($target, $acronym, $synonym)
```

Update 2:

```
// reading values from file:
$fp = fopen('dictionary.txt');

while (!eof($fp)) {
     $line = fgets($fp);

     $values = explode("/t", $line);

     //add to dictionary
     $myDict[$values[0]] = $values[1];
}

fclose($fp);
```

Comment: i might tweak it occasionally, but it's not something i'd do regularly. could you give an example?

Comment: I've updated my answer with some sample code, hope this helps.

Comment: how do i get it from a file into the array though?

Comment: this was good, but the other answer was more simple, and didn't involve iterating over the arrays. thank you anyway